# SQL Exist Predicate Explanation

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone please explain to me how EXIST works in SQL?

I am not entirely sure my result is working the way I need it to.

I just need an example using 3 different queries.

Please be very specific and explain it to me like you are talking to a 5 year old :)

Edit: Here is what I do not understand and need someone to make clear:

> The subquery will generally only be executed long enough to determine
>   whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion.
>   It is unwise to write a subquery that has side effects (such as
>   calling sequence functions); whether the side effects occur might be
>   unpredictable.
>
> Since the result depends only on whether any rows are returned, and
>   not on the contents of those rows, the output list of the subquery is
>   normally unimportant. A common coding convention is to write all
>   EXISTS tests in the form EXISTS(SELECT 1 WHERE ...). There are
>   exceptions to this rule however, such as subqueries that use
>   INTERSECT.

I am trying to create a query that selects values that do not exist in another query. Based on what I just quoted above, is this not a good idea to use EXISTS?

Edit Part 2: 
If I am trying to make sure a value doesn't exist in column 1 OR Column 2 OR column 3 OR column 4, should I use ALL or Exist?

My result looks weird with Exist, so I just wanted to make sure I understood it correctly, how it works.

Comment: what is not clear in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html)  ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Edited my post above. Sorry.